# Using databases and tables (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

On my website, customers have the option of creating an event with various items (that have attributes like seller, color, etc.). 
Should I have ONE database and a new table for each event? I don't know of another way to program this and splitting every customer/event into a new database seems like a bad solution, but I'm new to databases and don't know if that's stupid.

I assume that I'd have a TABLE with user IDs, a TABLE for each event, and a TABLE that links the user to the event(s) he/she created. Is this the optimal way to do this? All in one database?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is stupid. It is also stupid to have a separate table for each event. (As a rule of thumb, the database structure should be static: don't create new tables on the fly.)

Comment: So I should have ONE table with ALL the items, and have the event as a field? So I could search for all items with that field id, or search for a specific item in a specific event by using that id... that would make sense. Then I'd just need one more table for linking user IDs and event IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a one-to-many relationship between a user table, and an event table. The event table should have the user ID as a foreign key.

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    id int UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    last_modified timestamp NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE KEY (name)
);

CREATE TABLE event (
    id int UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    user_id int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    description varchar(500) NOT NULL,
    last_modified timestamp NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user.id ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

So then, you have your users, and when you add an event, you just assign the user_id to whatever user the event is for. Hopefully that gives you something to build from.

Comment: Wouldn't I want this to be a one-to-many relationship, since each event could only have one creater/user associated with it?

Comment: You are absolutely right! :), and that is what I illustrated at least. Was just a typo!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a small number of event types, and the event types are very different in nature (different properties) then you may create a different table for each event type.

However usually you will create one database with one table for all the events, with a column for event type or code (if needed). You also don't need to create a table that contain all the event types, your code can contain them. You table should contain only the actual events that were fired.